# POST Request to SharePoint List: The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetByTitle

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post, sharepoint

I am trying to finish this project for work and have run into this ridiculously annoying error. I have searched and searched on MSDN, Stack Overflow, and many other sites but cannot seem to find whats wrong. I found a post where someone was facing the same issue as me and they said the solution worked, but it gives me the same error as the beginning. Then, I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom) but it doesn't solve my issue.

The purpose of this POST request is to collect JSON data from an HTML form and send it to the corresponding SharePoint list. The purpose of sending it to a corresponding SharePoint list is so that my DataTable (which is on another subsite) can update through my GET request earlier in the code. I found this way to be the easiest route of updating the DataTable.

Here is the full error/alert (in JSON):

```
{
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetByTitle.\"}}}",
  "responseJSON": {
    "error": {
      "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
      "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetByTitle."
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400,
  "statusText": "error"
}
```

Here is my Code:

```js
function loadData() { //Initializing the AJAX Request function to load in the external list data from different subsites
        //create an array of urls to run through the ajax request instead of having to do multiple AJAX Requests
        var urls = ["/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes",
       "/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes",
            "/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
            "/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
            "/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
            "/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
            "/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
            "/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"
        ];
    
        for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) { //for loop to run through the AJAX until all URLs have been reached
            $.ajax({
                url: urls[i],
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function(data) { // success function which will then execute "GETTING" the data to post it to a object array (data.value)
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.d != null && data.d != undefined && data.d.results.length > 0) {
                        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
                        table.rows.add(data.d.results).draw();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var collapsedGroups = {};
        var top = '';
        var parent = '';
    
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "pageLength" : 50,
            "columns": [{
                    "data": "Program",
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    "data": "Deliverable",
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    "data": "To"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Date"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Approved"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Notes"
                }
            ],
    
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-10'f><'col-sm-12 col-md-2'B>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
            buttons: [{
                extend: 'collection',
                className: "btn-dark",
                text: 'Export/Update Table',
                buttons: [{
                        extend: "excel",
                        className: "btn-dark"
                    },
                    {
                        extend: "pdf",
                        className: "btn-dark"
                    },
                    {
                        extend: "print",
                        className: "btn-dark"
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Update Table',
                        action: function (e, dt, node, config){
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        },
                ],
            }],
            order: [
                [0, 'asc'],
                [1, 'asc']
            ],
            rowGroup: {
                dataSrc: [
                    'Program',
                    'Deliverable'
                ],
                startRender: function(rows, group, level) {
                    var all;
                    if (level === 0) {
                        top = group;
                        all = group;
                    } else if (level === 1) {
                        parent = top + group;
                        all = parent;
                        // if parent collapsed, nothing to do
                        if (!collapsedGroups[top]) {
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // if parent collapsed, nothing to do
                        if (!collapsedGroups[parent]) {
                            return;
                        }
                        all = top + parent + group;
                    }
    
                    var collapsed = !collapsedGroups[all];
                    console.log('collapsed:', collapsed);
    
                    rows.nodes().each(function(r) {
                        r.style.display = collapsed ? 'none' : '';
                    });
                    //Add category name to the <tr>.
                    return $('<tr/>')
                        .append('<td colspan="8">' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td>')
                        .attr('data-name', all)
                        .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
    
    
                }
    
            }
        });
    
        loadData();
    
        $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr.dtrg-start', function() {
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            collapsedGroups[name] = !collapsedGroups[name];
            table.draw(false);
        });
    
        $("#btn").click(function(e) {
            PostItem();
        });
    });
    
       function PostItem() {
        return getFormDigest("").then(function(digestData) {
            console.log(digestData.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue);
            $.ajax({
                async: true, // Async by default is set to “true” load the script asynchronously  
                // URL to post data into sharepoint list  or your own url
                url: "",
                method: "POST", //Specifies the operation to create the list item  
                data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true,
                'BaseTemplate': 100, 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My list description', 'Title': 'AMMO Deliverables' }
                ), 
            
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('Success'); // Used sweet alert for success message
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));

                }

            });
        })
    }
            function getItemTypeForListName(listName) {
                var itemType = "SP.Data." + listName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + listName.slice(1) + "ListName";
                var encItemType = itemType.replace(/\s/g,'_x0020_');
                return(encItemType);
    }       
        function getFormDigest(siteurl) {
    
            return $.ajax({
    
                url: "",
    
                method: 'POST',
    
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
                }
    
            });
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.2/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.2/css/rowGroup.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<link rel ="stylsheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<h1><strong>G3G Deliverables</strong></h1>
        <div class ="container">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Program</th>
                    <th>Deliverable</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Approved</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            </div>
             <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update DataTable</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="myform" type="post" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="myForm" runat="server">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend align="center">Update Datatable</legend>
                    <p>Please fill out the shown fields to add data to the DataTable</p>
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="program">Program :</label>
                    <select name = "program" id="dProgram">
                            <option value = "AHR">AHR</option>
                            <option value = "AMMO">AMMO</option>
                            <option value = "DAR-Q">DAR-Q</option>
                            <option value = "Doctrine Development">Doctrine Development</option>
                            <option value = "Operational Energy">Operational Energy</option>
                            <option value = "Ordnance Multimedia">Ordnance Multimedia</option>
                            <option value = "SRC Handbook">SRC Handbook</option>
                            <option value = "WTBn">WTBn</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="Deliverable">Deliverable :</label>
                    <select name="Deliverable" id="dDeliverable">
                            <option value = "Meeting Minutes">Meeting Minutes</option>
                            <option value = "Monthly Status Report (MSR)">Monthly Status Report (MSR)</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="To"> To:</label>
                    <input type="text" align= "center" id="dTo" name="To" placeholder="example@example.com">
                    </div>      
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="Date">Date: </label>
                    <input type="date" align= "center" id="dDate" name="Date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"> 
                    </div>  
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="Approved">Approved :</label>
                    <select name="Approved" id="dApproved">
                            <option value = "True">Yes</option>
                        <option value = "False">No</option></select>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="Notes"> Notes :</label>
                    <input type="text" align= "left" id="dNotes" name="Notes" placeholder="Please provide notes">
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                </SharePoint:FormDigest>
            </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<style>
```

This is the new error it throws after updating my code:

```
{
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.\"}}}",
  "responseJSON": {
    "error": {
      "code": "-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
      "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 403,
  "statusText": "error"
}
```

UPDATE:

Here is the following changes I made to my code(it yields the same 403 error):

```
function PostItem() {
            return getFormDigest(" ").then(function(digestData) {
                console.log(digestData.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue);
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.DeliverablesListItem" },
                    "Program": dProgram,
                    "Deliverable": dDeliverable,
                    "To": dTo,
                    "Date": dDate,
                    "Approved": dApproved,
                    "Notes": dNotes
                }),
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                    'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE',
                    'if-match': '*'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('player updated');
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.responseText);
                    console.log(msg);
                }

            }); 
            })
        }
```

Comment: So I have done some research, and this exception means "The protocol server requires a form digest but the form digest in the X-RequestDigest HTTP header is not as same as the one generated by the protocol server.". How do I figure out the one generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that there is no `__metdata` property on getbytitle

> The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetByTitle.

You should be able to change your `url` property to get rid of the `getbytitle` param in your url.

Example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists",
        type: "POST",
        data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true,
 'BaseTemplate': 100, 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My list description', 'Title': 'Test' }
),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-length": <length of post body>,
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: doSuccess,
        error: doError
});
```

UPDATE:

I found one of my old examples and I see a couple of issues:

1. The `SP.List` in the `__metdata` needs to be replaces with that specific `SP.List` type. (See example below)
2. You need to provide `etag` info (see example below)

Here's an old example I have of updating a SP List

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: uri,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.Seahawks_x0020_RosterListItem" },
                    "Title": newPlayer.name,
                    "Jersey_x0020_Number": newPlayer.jerseyNumber,
                    "Position": newPlayer.position,
                    "Height": newPlayer.height,
                    "Weight": newPlayer.weight,
                    "Age": newPlayer.age,
                    "Years_x0020_of_x0020_Experience": newPlayer.yoe,
                    "College": newPlayer.college
                }),
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                    'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE',
                    'if-match': etag
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    that.loadRoster();
                    alert('player updated');
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.responseText);
                    console.log(msg);
                }

            });
```

Here is the logic for getting the `etag`

```
getItemId: function (title, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Seahawks%20Roster')/items",
            dataType: 'json',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.Seahawks_x0020_RosterListItem" },
                "Title": title
            }),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {

                    var name = data.d.results[i].Title;

                    if (name == title) {
                        callback(data.d.results[i].Id, data.d.results[i].__metadata.etag, data.d.results[i].__metadata.uri);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.responseText);
                console.log(msg);
            }

        });

    },
```

Quite a few more examples of REST operations for SP here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

Comment: Testing this out now.

Comment: Yea. Seems kind of like the 400 bad request is getting thrown because the query to find the sp list is invalid

Comment: Check my most recent edit. I updated my script and now I am getting a 403 error..

Comment: Make sure you're adding your headers. Haven't worked with SP for a long time, but I remember the `"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()` being important

Comment: I understand that and I have it, I just cannot get this damn request to work for some reason. I have no issues with GET method, but POST is a pain in the arse!

Comment: And as for the <length of post body>, how do I figure out the size?

Comment: Could probably just do your `JSON.stringify` outside of your function and then run a string.length. I don't remember this being that important. I'm trying to find some of my old sp questions. I do remember POST requests being "different"

Comment: In my snippet, would you mind showing me what you mean with the JSON stringify.

Comment: I found one. Check out my update. There's a few more things you'll need to include in the request.

Comment: So I have had this question for a bit, if I do not use the title column item in my sharepoint list, must I include it? Also, for the parameters, would I change them to what the ID is in my HTML form for the input?

Comment: Yea, if I remember correctly, the title column is a required field so any upsert-type operation would fail if a required field is null.

Comment: Odd. I have it a hidden field surprised I still need it. Also, the etag what is that/where did it come from

Comment: You get that when you request to get the item to update. So, probably not needed on a create operation. I updated my code. Please remember to upvote/mark as answer if this helps/answers your question.

Comment: I get this error when Implementing it before my POST request. Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name

Comment: Sounds like you've specified a `function` without providing a name somewhere in your code. If you're copy/pasting from my code, that code follows the prototype style (old way of doing oop in js) so that's why those functions don't need names.

Comment: I had `"content-type": "application/json;odata=verSbose"`, with an added s, when i removed it the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got this error because I was posting but not updating ("PATCH"). Metadata apparently DOES exist on an update request.

So I needed the following headers settings:

```
headers: {    
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue,
    "IF-MATCH": "*",
    "X-Http-Method": "PATCH"
},
```

In my limited understanding `"X-Http-Method": "PATCH"` changes the POST to an update. I believe `"IF-MATCH": "*",` is necessary for this too, and you may have a different value instead of the "*" (anything).